# Tutorials to start learning Actionscript 3.0?

Tags: mysql, xml, actionscript-3

I already know Java, Objective C, C#, and some Python. I want to be able to integrate with XML or a MySQL database for dynamic content.

What are some tutorials or online references that would get me up and running with Actionscript 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just learned AS3, and the best thing I've found is the Essential Actionscript 3.0 book (Colin Moock, O'Reilly).  I know you asked for something online, but this book was far ahead of anything I was able to find online, and I should have bought it first.

Comment: Thanks for the book recommendation! I actually have that book but haven't really looked into it. With your advice, I think I'll focus on reading it :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some good tutorials available at [actionscript.org](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/categories/Tutorials/)